# Change workbench_moderation_state from select to radio

Tags: forms

I have workbench installed, and want to change the moderation status dropdown in the add node form to a radio.
But I don't get it. I have a custom module with a hook_form_alter hook which prints the $form array via

> dsm($form)

This does NOT print any workbench_moderation_state variable.
If I print it via print_r($form), I get a

```
 [...]
 [workbench_moderation_state_new] => Array ( 
   [#title] => Moderation status 
   [#type] => select 
   [#options] => Array (
     [needs_review] => Current: Needs Review
     [draft] => Draft
     [published] => Published
   )
   [#default_value] => needs_review
   [#description] => Moderationsstatus für diesen Inhalt setzen.
   [#access] => 1
 )
```

So it **has** to be there.

1. Why is the `workbench_moderation_state_new` Array not displayed in krumo via  `dsm()`, but printed via `print_r()`
2. (more important) Why the f**k does a simple

> $form['workbench_moderation_state_new']['#type'] = 'radio';
>   
>   not change the select into a radio, but introduce a new empty radio button in the form? I tried to follow the [Drupal form API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#type).

---

Argh. As almost always, I found the answer myself 5 minutes after posting here. Cost me 3 hours of searching and try-and-error before. `workbench_moderation_state_new` is a sub-array of `options`.

So a `$form['options']['workbench_moderation_state_new']['#type'] = 'radios';` does the trick. Mind 'radios' instead of 'radio' as well. For anyone interested.
Problem solved.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`$form['options']['workbench_moderation_state_new']['#type'] = 'radios';` does the trick.
I just forgot the `['options']` array.